# Which font is this?

Tags: fonts

I would be glad if someone would tell me which font is this:

[image]

I'm in need of css font for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a font called "Erato" in bold. May also be "Arno Pro" in display bold. Looks uncommon

Comment: No problem, Love to help! :)

Comment: Just to be 100% acurate it's arno pro in bold :)